# Detect unprotected code using cppdepend to audit missing outer guard in call chain?

Tags: c++, concurrency, cppdepend

I'm trying to detect code which is unprotected by a guard clause at a higher level in its callers. I think I can get quite close with [cppdepend](http://www.cppdepend.com/) but unsure if I can precisely identify problems.

I have a bunch of code where a locking protection is required so we have an assertion at the innermost functions:

```
assert(eventQueue.IsCurrentEventGuarded());
```

Note that `eventQueue` is a static instance of type `EventQueue`.

I want to detect all places where the functions containing that assertion are invoked and there is **not** an instance of a guard object at *some* point in their caller chain.

So, it is OK if at some point in the caller chain there is an expression:

```
GSEventGuard guard;
```

However, if the call to `IsCurrentEventGuarded` occurs without that protective instance *somewhere* above it, we have a problem that should be detected.

I can find the upper-level *Guarding Methods* which create the guard (ie: good ones we can ignore) with a clause:

```
SELECT METHODS WHERE IsDirectlyUsing "GSEventGuard" AND 
   IsUsing "EventQueue.IsCurrentEventGuarded()"
```

Ideally I should be able to ignore everything above and below those methods.

A more interesting clause finds two sets of methods - those *below* the *Guarding Methods* (between a guard and the test) and those which are in the calling chains we want, unprotected.

```
SELECT METHODS WHERE
DepthOfIsUsing "EventQueue.IsCurrentEventGuarded()" > 1
AND !(IsUsing "GSEventGuard.try_lock()" OR IsUsing "GSEventGuard.lock()")
ORDER BY DepthOfIsUsing DESC
```

finds 65 methods which are either in the calling chain below a lock or higher up and unguarded